# Integrating flask api in flutter application

Tags: flutter, api, flask, integration

I am trying to build a flutter project, in which i need to integrate flask api with flutter app, I have tried to integrate it but it is showing some error and i am not getting what the error is or may be my flutter code is wrong.

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import joblib
import traceback
from flask_restful import reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "hello"


@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    model = joblib.load("model.joblib")
    shortness_of_breath = request.form.get('shortness of breath')
    dizziness = request.form.get('dizziness')
    asthenia = request.form.get('asthenia')
    fall = request.form.get('fall')
    syncope = request.form.get('syncope')

    input_query = np.array([[shortness_of_breath,dizziness,asthenia,fall,syncope]])

    result = model.predict(input_query)[0]

    return jsonify({'disease':str(result)})       
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Below is the flutter code that i have tried to integrate the flask API, I want to create a page to predict the disease where the user will select the five symptoms mentioned in ('final data'), if the user selects the symptoms then the value should be '1.0' otherwise it should be '0.0' .

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class Test_Http extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test_Http({super.key});

  @override
  State<Test_Http> createState() => _Test_HttpState();
}

Future<String> predictDisease(Map<String, String> data) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict'),
    body: data,
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final result = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return result['disease'];
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
}

class _Test_HttpState extends State<Test_Http> {
  String _disease = '';
  void _predictDisease() async {
    final data = {
      'shortness of breath': '1.0',
      'dizziness': '0.0',
      'asthenia': '1.0',
      'fall': '0.0',
      'syncope': '1.0',
    };
    final disease = await predictDisease(data);
    setState(() {
      _disease = disease;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Testing Flask Api"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Predicted Disease:",
            ),
            Text("$_disease"),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _predictDisease,
              child: Text("Predict"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which error message did you get? What have you tried?

Comment: And do you run the app on a browser on the same host as the Flask server? I mean `127.0.0.1` points to `localhost` which is the mobile device if you run it on Android or iOS. So you need to replace it with the local ip of your server host.

Comment: Thankyou for the response, so the error i was getting "ClientException (Connection reset by peer)" I somehow fixed it by using timeout(Duration(seconds :30)), and i am running on local host i.e 127.0.0.1, but i am testing it on android emulator so i replaced it with 10.0.2.2